# HP laptop sleep after few minutes

Tags: windows-8, laptop, sleep

I'm using HP Probook G2 laptop. I don't know why my laptop goes to sleep after few minutes. It doesn't go to sleep after specific time, sometimes it takes long but sometimes short period. I have set "Never" sleep and "Never" turn off display in Power Options. Is there anyone who experienced this issue before?

Kaspersky has been installed on my laptop, is it a cause? Or maybe some other program?

Comment: Did your laptop come with any preinstalled governing power management software?

Answer (score 0):

Is it connected to power or on battery ?
Note that on-battery power rules are different from the ones applied when the notebook is not on battery.
If you changed the settings, make sure you changed them for both cases.

Comment: It's connected to power

Comment: Try taking a look into the registry at [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\User\PowerSchemes\  to see if anything is wrong there. For "never" ACSettingIndex should be dword:00000000 .  Alternately, just imput into a command prompt "powercfg -change -standby-timeout-ac" and thatll make sure everything is set.